# Resistive heating cuircuit design

Tags: pcb, heat, trace

I am designing a small (10mm^2) resistive-based heater. I wish to heat a ceramic surface to about 250°C, via some high frequency AC-current. My aim to is have some sort of high-temperature PCB printed in order to fit long enough (to get high resistance/low current) and counter-winded trace (to avoid induced magnetic fields). I am looking for some high-fusion point and high-resistivity traces and a proper material to print the circuit (PCB will melt at those temperature...).

Could anyone let me know which materials are available?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Why high frequency? Isabellenhuette resistors comes to mind.

Comment: Hello and thank you !
The main requirement for this setup is to minimize magnetic noise in the low frequency regime (this piece is part of a setup to measure magnetic fields). For this, I wish to use high-frequency current such as to get magnetic induction in the high-frequency regime where my sensors are mostly insensitive. This is also why I would need high resistance rather than high current: high current produces strong magnetic fields.

Comment: Good! Still Isabellenhuette resistors :-)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look. But I am afraid those resistors have some magnetic induction to them. I will get in touch with them still !

Comment: Some Finish resistive paste on ceramic plates comes to mind too. Can't recall if it was this one. I'll look more for you. http://inkron.com/products/conductive-inks/